# Castle Active Record in Medium Trust?

Tags: c#, .net, castle-activerecord, medium-trust

I have downloaded the Active Record and NHibernate and compiled both with the flag "AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers". But I'm still getting errors in the method "ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize" on the "medium trust" environment.

Does anyone have the ActiveRecord (3.0 or higher) running at .net 3.5 or 4 "medium trust"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this on july/2012 and posted on my company blog. http://isul.com.br/blog/index.php/archives/936